# Multidimensional array of objects that retrieves the id, title, and smallest box art URL for every video

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to simplify this code?

```
// array    
const movieLists = [
        {
            name: "New Releases",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
                        { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 654356453,
                    "title": "Bad Boys",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
                        { width: 140, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" }

                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Thrillers",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 65432445,
                    "title": "The Chamber",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 130, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },
                        { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 675465,
                    "title": "Fracture",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
                        { width: 120, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
                        { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    const arr1 = movieLists
        .map(function (outterItem) {
            return outterItem.videos
                .map(function (innerItem) {
                    return [innerItem.boxarts
                        .reduce(function (acc, currentValue) {
                            if (acc.width * acc.height < currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
                                return acc
                            } else {
                                return currentValue
                            }
                        })]
                        .map(function (lastItem) {
                            return {
                                id: innerItem.id,
                                title: innerItem.title,
                                boxart: lastItem.url
                            }
                        })
                })
        })


    // flatten deep 
    const newArray = (function flattenDeep(arr1) {
            return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
        })(arr1);

    console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Arrow Functions and ternaries

I'll start by saying that you can simplify syntactically using ternaries and ES6 [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without losing readability. These will make the code look smaller and simpler, despite being the same solution.

It would look like this:

```
const arr1 = movieLists.map(outterItem => 
    outterItem.videos.map(innerItem => 
        [innerItem.boxarts
            .reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc.width * acc.height < currentValue.width * currentValue.height ? 
                acc : 
                currentValue
            )
        ]
        .map(lastItem => 
            ({
                id: innerItem.id,
                title: innerItem.title,
                boxart: lastItem.url
            })
        )
    )
)
```

### Naming

The names you gave in to some variables/parameters aren't very good and make the code somewhat hard to read.

For instance in the maps:

```
.map(function (outterItem) {
    return outterItem.videos
        .map(function (innerItem) {
```

Both `outterItem` and `innerItem` are too vague to actually mean anything. And you can't really know what they hold unless you take a another look at the data. The `outterItem` is the first level object of the array, which is a sort of category object, while the `innerItem` would be each video of the `videos` array.

### Solution

The solution itself seems overly complex for the problem at hand, because you do a double `map`, to a `reduce`, to a final `map`. And then you *flatten* the result with `reduce`. Then *flatten* is needed because the generated structure is deeper than you needed it to be.

A way simpler solution would be:

- 2 `for` loops to run through each video
- Find the smallest box art in the video with `reduce`
- Add the desired object to the resulting array with `push`

This avoids the need to *flatten* anything.

Following this logic, the whole code would become:

```
const finalVideos = []
for (let category of movieLists){
    for (let video of category.videos){
        const smallestBoxArt = video.boxarts.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.width * acc.height < curr.width * curr.height ? acc : curr)
        finalVideos.push({
            id: video.id,
            title: video.title,
            boxart: smallestBoxArt.url
        });
    }
}

console.log(finalVideos)
```

If you feel the reduce line as a bit too long or just repeats the area code too much, you can even create a simple function for it:

```
const area = obj => obj.width * obj.height;
```

And change the `reduce` to use it:

```
const smallestBoxArt = video.boxarts.reduce((acc, curr)=>area(acc) < area(curr) ? acc:curr)
```